# inserting values from a webform that has a field for value in different table

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, webforms

I'm working on an assignment where I have to fill in information in a web form, then insert that information into a local database, however one of the fields on the webform is associated with a different table in the database, and I am unsure how to implement a join that can perform this.

My Database:

Player
- (PK)PlayerID
- PlayerName
- JerseyNumber

Statistic
- (PK)StatId
- PlayerId
- MatchesPlayed
- MatchesWon
- Assists
- Goals
- Points

My WebForm Requests:

Player Name - Dropdown,
Matches Played - Text Box,
Matches Won - Text Box,
Assists - Text Box,
Goals - Text Box,
Add Button

Heres what i have in the Button click event

```
tblStatistic = (DataTable)Cache["tbl"];

            DataRow newRow = tblStatistic.NewRow();
            newRow["StatID"] = 0;

            newRow["MatchesPlayed"] = txtMatchesPlayed.Text;
            newRow["MatchesWon"] = txtMatchesWon.Text;
            newRow["Assists"] = txtAssists.Text;
            newRow["Goals"] = txtGoals.Text;
            tblStatistic.Rows.Add(newRow);

            adapter.InsertCommand = cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
            int rowsAffected = adapter.Update(tblStatistic);

            if (rowsAffected == 1)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Stats inserted";
                lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Stat not inserted";
                lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
```

the error i get says "'PlayerId' does not allow nulls."

Comment: In order to link the player and statistics tables, you need to add the same player id to both tables.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I have to get that player ID when the "user" selects a players name from a dropdown @MariosNikolaou

Comment: Ok, when the user selects player get the ID and insert it to statistics table as foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you want to add row in Statistic  you have to pass id of player as a FK 
just add this line to your code i hope it works
   newRow["PlayerID"] = int.parse(drpPlayer.selectedvalue);

it will be :
tblStatistic = (DataTable)Cache["tbl"];

            DataRow newRow = tblStatistic.NewRow();
            newRow["StatID"] = 0;
            newRow["PlayerID"] = int.parse(drpPlayer.selectedvalue);
            newRow["MatchesPlayed"] = txtMatchesPlayed.Text;
            newRow["MatchesWon"] = txtMatchesWon.Text;
            newRow["Assists"] = txtAssists.Text;
            newRow["Goals"] = txtGoals.Text;
            tblStatistic.Rows.Add(newRow);



            adapter.InsertCommand = cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
            int rowsAffected = adapter.Update(tblStatistic);

            if (rowsAffected == 1)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Stats inserted";
                lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Stat not inserted";
                lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
```